# How is number of messages counted

Tags: azure-iot-hub

When there is no device connected to the IoT Hub, the number of messages count increases.

We were trying to find out the number of messages counted when sending a one-way D-to-Do message, and the results we got was 3 messages (1 C-to-D, two twin messages). However, when we tried it again, the total number of messages became 9, and only C-to-D message count increased to 2 while the twin message count remained the same.

To clarify, we closed both devices and tried to investigate on the Hub, but the message count kept increasing each time when we refreshed the chart, and it has increased to 22 messages by now.

Does anyone know how the number of messages is actually counted? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kevin just trying to make sure I understand the question. It looks like the device twin messages count increases every time you refresh the chart in the portal?

Comment: Hi Alberto, actually the device twin message count shown in the chart look right, and so does the C-to-D message count. It is the message count shown in the Iot Hub Usage in the portal just keeps increasing, and we can't figure out where those messages are from.  Thank you

Comment: If you have access to a support plan please create a support ticket. If you don't we can help you get a one time free support ticket please reach out to AZCommunity@microsoft.com with a link to this thread and your subscription id

Comment: Hi Alberto, email sent.  Thank you so much